# unity3D вращение объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

Неделю назад начал изучать движок Unity, сейчас не могу разобраться с вращением. Допустим есть стрелка (представьте, например, стрелку спидометра), задача - наклонять эту стрелку так, как она наклонялась бы будучи на условном спидометре. Т.е нижняя точка этой стрелки должна быть статична, а верхняя должна вращаться.
Надеюсь, у меня получилось достаточно доходчиво объяснить, чего я хочу :)

Answer (score 3):

Нужно установить pivot point вниз спрайта - тогда вращение будет вокруг этой точки.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpriteEditor.html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Нужно осуществить вращение вокруг заданной точки (cx, cy)
Для этого формируется матрица аффинного преобразования, составленная из произведения матриц

```
переноcа на (-cx, -cy)
поворота вокруг начала координат на нужный угол
переноса обратно на (cx, cy)
```

Возможно, уже имеется функция задания готовой матрицы, что-нибудь вроде `RotateAround`. Upd - да, [есть](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html)

Comment: Огромное спасибо, вопрос решен!